# Different color for plot outside range

Tags: highcharts

For Highstocks / Highcharts : 
http://jsfiddle.net/josse34/5gjne/8/

I would like to automaticly change color of plot outside range (change color of line, plot and/or better : area!) to red, how to make this?
I found a exemple but VERY complicated !!! http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10433

```
$(function () {
var ranges = [
        [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
        [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
        [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
        [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7],
        [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
        [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7],
        [1246924800000, 13.5, 24.8],
        [1247011200000, 10.5, 21.4],
        [1247097600000, 9.2, 23.8],
        [1247184000000, 11.6, 21.8],
        [1247270400000, 10.7, 23.7],
        [1247356800000, 11.0, 23.3],
        [1247443200000, 11.6, 23.7],
        [1247529600000, 11.8, 20.7],
        [1247616000000, 12.6, 22.4],
        [1247702400000, 13.6, 19.6],
        [1247788800000, 11.4, 22.6],
        [1247875200000, 13.2, 25.0],
        [1247961600000, 14.2, 21.6],
        [1248048000000, 13.1, 17.1],
        [1248134400000, 12.2, 15.5],
        [1248220800000, 12.0, 20.8],
        [1248307200000, 12.0, 17.1],
        [1248393600000, 12.7, 18.3],
        [1248480000000, 12.4, 19.4],
        [1248566400000, 12.6, 19.9],
        [1248652800000, 11.9, 20.2],
        [1248739200000, 11.0, 19.3],
        [1248825600000, 10.8, 17.8],
        [1248912000000, 11.8, 18.5],
        [1248998400000, 10.8, 16.1]
    ],
    averages = [
        [1246406400000, 21.5],
        [1246492800000, 22.1],
        [1246579200000, 23],
        [1246665600000, 23.8],
        [1246752000000, 21.4],
        [1246838400000, 21.3],
        [1246924800000, 18.3],
        [1247011200000, 15.4],
        [1247097600000, 16.4],
        [1247184000000, 17.7],
        [1247270400000, 17.5],
        [1247356800000, 17.6],
        [1247443200000, 17.7],
        [1247529600000, 16.8],
        [1247616000000, 17.7],
        [1247702400000, 16.3],
        [1247788800000, 17.8],
        [1247875200000, 18.1],
        [1247961600000, 17.2],
        [1248048000000, 14.4],
        [1248134400000, 30.7],
        [1248220800000, 15.7],
        [1248307200000, 14.6],
        [1248393600000, 15.3],
        [1248480000000, 15.3],
        [1248566400000, 15.8],
        [1248652800000, 15.2],
        [1248739200000, 14.8],
        [1248825600000, 14.4],
        [1248912000000, 15],
        [1248998400000, 13.6]
    ];


    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: 'July temperatures'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: averages,
            zIndex: 1,
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Range',
            data: ranges,
            type: 'arearange',
            lineWidth: 0,
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            color: 'green',
            zIndex: 0
        }]

    });    
});
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: To clarify you want that big spike that is outside of the green band to be a different color and/or you want that spike's area to be a different color?

Comment: Hi Wergeld!
I would like exactly like this picture : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/806869High1.jpg
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you would like to have colored area between series, based on any condition, you need to use 3 series as in related topic is.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!
Have you a good and simply exemple with link of jsfiddle??
Thanks

Comment: Thanks but it's complicated to use (and calculate) 2 différents range, there are not any other method?

Comment: Unfortunately it is the only way.

Comment: Ok, only way for color of area, but if i want just coloring the plot outside range? Thanks!

Comment: Which one, "above/below" your green area, or somewhere different?

Comment: So sorry, your post was hidden!!! So i would like to coloring plot outside range but only below range! Thanks

Comment: I would like to coloring plot outside range but only below range! Thanks –

Comment: You can add extra serie, (area type) and set custom color

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any exemple? best is a jsdfiddle link! Thanks!